# ¿Cómo reemplazar un ciclo For en pandas python para reducir tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Tengo el siguiente DataFrame simplificado (el real tiene 26 millones de registros):

```
df:
     id D1   D2   D3   D4
0   111  A    B    C    D
1   222  B    C    D  NaN
2   333  C    A  NaN  NaN
3   444  A  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   111  A    E    C    M
5   333  C    M  NaN  NaN
6   555  D    E  NaN  NaN
7   111  E    A    B  NaN
8   444  F  NaN  NaN  NaN
9   333  G    A  NaN  NaN
10  666  H    N  NaN  NaN
```

Requiero obtener los siguientes registros por cada `id`: 
1. Número de registros en la base 
2. Número de valores diferentes de `D`
3. Número total de `D`

El código usado es el siguiente:

```
iden = df['id'].unique().tolist()
reporte=pd.DataFrame(columns=['ide','n_c','n_dif','n_total'])
for i in iden: 
    c = df[df['id'] == i]
    d = c['D1'].append([c['D2'], c['D3'], c['D4']]) 
    d = d.dropna()  
    d_dif = d.drop_duplicates()
    reporte=reporte.append({'ide':i,'n_c':len(c),'n_dif':len(d_dif) ,'n_total': len(d)},ignore_index=True)
```

y el resultado obtenido es:

```
   ide n_c n_dif n_total
0  111   3     6      11
1  222   1     3       3
2  333   3     4       6
3  444   2     2       2
4  555   1     2       2
5  666   1     2       2
```

Requiero encontrar un camino en pandas para reemplazar el `for` que busca los registros de cada `id` en la base de datos, puesto que se demora aproximadamente un segundo en la búsqueda y realización del cálculo por `id`, lo que es muy ineficiente si se tiene en cuenta el tamaño de la base.

Agradezco si me pueden ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer, es construir una función que procese cada grupo:

```
def stats(x):

  complete_list = [item for sublist in x.values.tolist() for item in sublist]
  without_nan = [item for item in complete_list if item is not np.nan]
  d = {}
  d['n_c'] = len(x)
  d['n_dif'] = len(set(without_nan))
  d['n_total'] = len(without_nan)

  return pd.Series(d)
```

Como se puede apreciar, la función `stats` convierte todos los valores de todas las columnas recibidas en una simple lista, luego simplemente usamos ésta para los cálculos y retornamos una `Serie` que serán nuestras columnas nuevas.

Luego simplemente aplicamos las función a cada grupo:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['id'])[['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4']].apply(stats)

print(grouped)
         n_c  n_dif  n_total
id                      
111    3      6       11
222    1      3        3
333    3      4        6
444    2      2        2
555    1      2        2
666    1      2        2
```

Al menos con este conjunto de datos, se logra reducir los tiempos a la tercera parte con respecto a lo que ya estás haciendo, pero deberías probarlo con el conjunto completo de los datos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Partiendo de `groupby`, hay dos columnas cuyo cálculo es muy simple de forma vectorizada:

- Para `n_c` basta con usar `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.size`
- Para `n_total` podemos usar `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.count` seguido de `sum` para sumar cada fila. `count` descarta los `NaN` por defecto.

El problema está en obtener los valores únicos para cada grupo teniendo en cuenta todas las columnas. En este caso lo mejor que se me ha ocurrido ha sido usar `pandas.unique` sobre una vista del array aplanado, lo cual nos genera un array con los items únicos, seguido de `pandas.Series.count` para contar los items descartando los NaN.

```
groups = df.groupby("id")
reporte = pd.DataFrame({
    'n_c': groups.size(),
    'n_dif': groups[['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4']].apply(
        lambda group: pd.Series(pd.unique(group.values.ravel())).count()),
    'n_total': groups.count().sum(axis=1)}
    )
```

El ejemplo completo reproducible:

```
import io
import pandas as pd



data = io.StringIO("""\
  id D1   D2   D3   D4
111  A    B    C    D
222  B    C    D  NaN
333  C    A  NaN  NaN
444  A  NaN  NaN  NaN
111  A    E    C    M
333  C    M  NaN  NaN
555  D    E  NaN  NaN
111  E    A    B  NaN
444  F  NaN  NaN  NaN
333  G    A  NaN  NaN
666  H    N  NaN  NaN 
""")


df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+", engine="python")


groups = df.groupby("id")
reporte = pd.DataFrame({
    'n_c': groups.size(),
    'n_dif': groups[['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4']].apply(
        lambda group: pd.Series(pd.unique(group.values.ravel())).count()),
    'n_total': groups.count().sum(axis=1)}
    )
```

> ```
> >>> reporte
>      n_c  n_dif  n_total
> id                      
> 111    3      6       11
> 222    1      3        3
> 333    3      4        6
> 444    2      2        2
> 555    1      2        2
> 666    1      2        2
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias!